# How can I stop a modal from closing when I press the ESC key so that a function is called instead that checks if the data has been saved?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

For the moment I have managed with HostListener to call that method but this should happen without closing the modal.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
if(this.deleteIsAllowed()){
 this.showDialogForClosing();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to use `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()`.

Can you please give us the library name you are using? Sometimes you can configure the closing behaviour of the modal.

Comment: I tried in the past with event.stopPropagation() and it didn't work, but with event.preventDefault() the behavior is the one I wanted. Thank you!